# Convert string to an object

Tags: android, string, list, object, type-conversion

I have 3 string list and I want to add all values to menus but it gives error which is "Invalid index 0, size is 0". Briefly, menus is null and how can I add them?

```
private List<List<Restaurant.Menu>> menus = new ArrayList<>();

ArrayList<String> MenuName = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> FoodName = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> FoodPrice = new ArrayList<>();

//I get values in DB. DB is full.
MenusName = tinydb.getListString("MenuName");
FoodName = tinydb.getListString("FoodName");
FoodPrice = tinydb.getListString("FoodPrice");

int restaurantCounter = 0;
int menuCounter = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < MenusName.size(); j++)
{
     menus.get(restaurantCounter).get(j).name = MenusName.get(j))
}
```

Example, I created them for each value, it works but if string is long, it enforces app and I wait 10 sec. for this process. I need efficient way. Thanks in advance.

```
menus.get(resCounter).add(new Restaurant.Menu());
menus.get(resCounter).get(menuCounter).foods.add(new Restaurant.Food());    
.
.

menus.get(resCounter).get(menuCounter).name = MenuName.get(i));
menus.get(resCounter).get(menuCounter).foods.get(foodCounter).name = FoodName.get(i);
menus.get(resCounter).get(menuCounter).foods.get(foodCounter).price = FoodPrice.get(i);
```

Comment: In your code you aren't adding anything to any of the lists you make before calling get on them.  You can't do that, or you'll get an IndexOutOfBounds exception.  Lists aren't like arrays, they don't have a fixed size.

Comment: It is part of my code. I get all values in db. Strings have values. I need to add them to menus. Any suggestion?

Comment: Post your code.  Because you aren't adding anything in the code you posted already.   Also you create a new array list then overwrite it in your first block, which makes me doubt you understand what the code does.

Comment: Code is very long. I added some parts.

Comment: menus.get(restaurantCounter).get(j).name   THat's wrong.  You have to add items to a list before you can access them.  list.get(x) throws an exception unless you've added at least x items to it.

Comment: ArrayList<String> MenuNames = new ArrayList<>(); I added all values to MenuNames in for loop. After that, menus.get(0).get(0).name.equals(MenuNames); and It gives the same error. Also, I tried ArrayList<Object>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution so I changed structure. I get all strings in restaurants and I used gson to convert them before store them. Also you can use gson for each string. It it same logic.

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 ArrayList<String> gsonString = new ArrayList<>();
 for(int i=0; i<restaurants.size(); i++)
     gsonString.add(gson.toJson(restaurants.get(i)));
 tinydb.putListString("tinyRestaurant",gsonString);
```

Convert again...

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 for(int i=0; i<tinydb.getListString("tinyRestaurant").size(); i++)
        restaurants.add(gson.fromJson(tinydb.getListString("tinyRestaurant").get(i), Restaurant.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing arrays with lists here. Arrays have a fixed size once initialised, Lists don't. You need to add something to your `menus` list using `menus.add(/*Add Menu Object here*/);`

Comment: I can't use menus.get(restaurantCounter).get(menuCounter).name.add(), i have to use menus.get(restaurantCounter).get(menuCounter).name.equals(object)

Comment: You must add something to the `menus` list before you try to access it using `menus.get(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't add any values to `menus`.so the object doesn't contain value at the index 0. This might be a reason.